# Avoid viewstate to display on website source code

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have performance issue on website,  because of too long viewstate in source code. on some pages it's size is more than 15-20kb. Which is increasing the load time on browser.

Is there any way to disable viewstate partially or fully without any harm on other module of website. FYI there is one listview and one form on these example pages. where viewstate is very long.

More Example pages

http://www.pricingindia.in/coupons/ebay-in-coupon-codes-20

http://www.pricingindia.in/coupons/flipkart-coupon-codes-32

Comment: 15 or 20kb really isn't much at all unless we are talking mobile apps.  On your site you have javascript, true type fonts, style sheets and jpegs that are all larger than that.  This is not your issue.  According to Chrome's dev tools the site spent 6.4 seconds trying to load jsapi and 4 seconds loading a clear.png file from google; these were by far your biggest offenders.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even click on the links @ChrisLively (I just assumed the OP had done the proper analysis to determine ViewState was the issue).  I guess that makes my answer kind of pointless haha.

Comment: Regarding how long it takes to render once downloaded, your site uses a lot of percentages on widths.  Any time you use a percentage the browser's layout engine has to take time to compute where things go using multiple passes, making the site appear far slower than it actually is.  Use actual defined widths, not percentages.

Comment: Last thing I'm looking at on this (and there are several other things you should be doing...): Why on earth are you embedding image data in your CSS and HTML files?  Doing that increases the load time of the CSS when the browser could have been downloading them in a separate thread thereby speeding up the experience. Bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to disable for ViewState for your Page in general, and then only enable ViewState for the controls that need / use it.

See [this MSDN page on the `Control.ViewStateMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx), it describes how to set that up:

> To disable view state for a page and to enable it for a specific
>   control on the page, set the EnableViewState property of the page and
>   the control to true, set the ViewStateMode property of the page to
>   Disabled, and set the ViewStateMode property of the control to
>   Enabled.

You will need to do some testing to see which controls need / use the ViewState in your specific app.  But, basically,

- anything that's static, you can disable the ViewState (Buttons, LinkButtons, etc).
- Any controls whose state doesn't need to be restored between PostBacks, you can disable ViewState (such as a TextBox in a form that is submitted to the server, and then cleared).
- Any controls that need to keep their state between PostBacks, you want to enable Viewstate (this would often be databound controls like GridViews / etc).

Doing this should definitely reduce the load that ViewState is putting on your pages.

Comment: +1 because this answers the question and is a good idea regardless of the plethora of more pressing performance issues the OP has.

Comment: Heh, thanks @Chris.  You should post those comments as an answer (if you have the time / inclination), I think they would make a great resolution to the OPs problems.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I couldn't leave well enough alone:

Firebug said the following bit of code blocked the site from rendering for about 6 seconds.  I thought it was the jsapi (based on info from chrome's tools) but the following returned a "502 Bad Gateway" message meaning that it sat there spinning it's wheels unable to process while preventing your web page from displaying.

I would move the `<script ..`  call to the header, where it belongs.  Then I'd move the `google.load` and `google.setOnLoadCallback` to the bottom of the web page so it runs last.

Finally I'd figure out exactly why it's failing to work right.

Homework for you: get Firebug loaded into firefox and learn how to use it's Net tools to see where site loading issues are.

```
<div class="sr_bx1 FL clearfix">
 <div class="FL searchbg">
         <div id='cse' style='width: 100%;'>Loading</div>
        <script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>  
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            google.load('search', '1', { language: 'en', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT });
            google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                var customSearchOptions = {};
                var orderByOptions = {};
                orderByOptions['keys'] = [{ label: 'Relevance', key: '' }, { label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
                customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
                customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
                var imageSearchOptions = {};
                imageSearchOptions['layout'] = 'google.search.ImageSearch.LAYOUT_POPUP';
                customSearchOptions['enableImageSearch'] = true;
                customSearchOptions['overlayResults'] = true;
                var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('010882286766777081969:xkox132izzk', customSearchOptions);
                customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
                var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
                options.setAutoComplete(true);
                customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
            }, true);
        </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Great work Chris, I implemented the solution. I replaced this google code with new one.[ http://www.pricingindia.in ] and now it's improved a lot on performance. But still my question is regarding Viewstate. I heard somewhere, we can save it on session. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using Page Adapter Class, you can solve this problem. I found following solution helpful for ASP.NET Web Application:

view state serialization is handled by an object of type PageStatePersister. (The PageStatePersister class is an abstract class that defines the base-level functionality for serializing view state to some persistent medium.)

**Steps:**
**1)** In Your Web Application, Add Folder: `App_Browsers`
**2)** In this folder, Add new BrowserFile: `ViewStateAdapter.browser`
**3)** Write following code in it:

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Default">
      <controlAdapters>
        <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.Page" adapterType="ServerSideViewStateAdapter" />
      </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

**4)** In Your WebApplication, Add Folder: `App_Code`
**5)** In this folder, Add new ClassFile: `ServerSideViewStateAdapter.cs`
**6)** Write following code in it:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.Adapters;
public class ServerSideViewStateAdapter : PageAdapter
{
    public override System.Web.UI.PageStatePersister GetStatePersister()
    {
        return new SessionPageStatePersister(this.Page);
    }
}
```

You can refer this video, it can help you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36pmFySbXZA

Comment: don't just post links as answer, as this link may change in future and may not be of any use for future. Better you write some important content from link.